# Uploading ebook files to a Kobo Aura One

Tags: linux, ebooks

https://www.kobo.com/desktop

offers a software to handle ebook collections and upload it to Kobo ebook readers.

Unfortunately, it works only on Windows and Mac.

I am thinking on buying a Kobo ebook reader but it is not clear whether I can use Linux to manage my ebooks and upload them to the reader with a USB cable.

What software do I need on Linux to connect to a Kobo ebook reader? Can I simply use it as an external drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best software for e-book management in Windows, Linux and macOS it's [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com). It can handle a variety of devices, including Kobo.
Written in Python 2.7, it's updated quite often.

In the help section of the website there is a FAQ for Kobo devices, if something doesn't work as expected.

The installation of Calibre it's easy: from the download page, copy the shell commands, and run them in a Terminal. It uses "sudo" from your user login. If you don't use "sudo", switch to root, remove the "sudo" command from the shell commands and re-run the commands.
The shell commands will download the install script.

The script will install Calibre in /opt/Calibre. Start the program from the menu of your desktop environment. A small wizard will help you to configure Calibre for the first time.

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

Just upload this on kobo like on regular flash drive and it will import your file.